# why time.timezone negative value even though my tz is UTC+5.30

Tags: python, python-3.x

Apologies for asking this basic question. But I am having allot of confusions in python's "time and timezone" calculations. I think this is because, there have too many solutions in python to just calculate time.

My doubt is:

```
import time
time.time()
1661680722.0567589
time.timezone
-19800
```

My timezone is UTC+5.30. I expect time.time is equivalent to utc time. So, time.timezone should be a positive value equivalent to 5.30 hours. Isn't so? Why it is coming negative value ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation `time.timezone` returns:

```
The offset of the local (non-DST) timezone, in seconds west of UTC (negative in most of Western Europe, positive in the US, zero in the UK). See note below.
```

So it makes sense that it returns negative value as 19800 seconds is indeed 5.5 hours.